# Select2-Field does't get selected with Selenium and Python only in Firefox

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I just try to automate a couple of things with selenium and python.
In my formular I got a few select2-fields which should be selected with selenium.
If I try this with the chrome-browser it works without problems, but if I switch to firefox the select-fields are empty.
If I print the error I get `'str' object is not callable`.

I implement the webdriver with:

```
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=GeckoDriverManager().install())
```

This is the code where I try to select a value:

```
try:
        css_selector = "#my_select .select2-search__field"
        self.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR(css_selector)).send_keys("Test")
        self.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR(css_selector)).send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

I also tried it with this, but it also doesn't work:

```
select = Select(self.get_element_by_id('my_select'))
    select.select_by_value("Test)
```

Can someone help me with this problem?

@KunduK:

```
    <select name="my_select" class="form-group select sr_validate_nonempty" id="my_select">
                        <option value="1">Value1</option>
                        <option value="2">Value2</option>
                        <option value="3">Value3</option>
                        <option value="4">Value4</option>
                    </select>
```

Comment: Please share your html or url?